# Execute a stored procedure within a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, case-when

I have an `Insert Into Select` statement with a `Case When` clause. I want to execute a stored procedure within the `When` statement.

```
Insert into Orders(id, custId, custIntake)
Select id, custId custIntake = 
   Case
     When ( Exec mySProc(custId) = 1 ) = 'InStore'
     When ( Exec mySProc(custId) = 0 ) = 'OutsideStore'
     Else null
   End
From OrdersImport
```

How can I run `Exec mySProc(custId)` within the `Case When`?

Comment: Personally I would probably run this as a function rather than a stored procedure. Unless there is a reason why you need to have this as stored procedure. Alternatively can you not work out the stored procedure value before doing the insert eg pass a variable in that has the value already calculated unless you are doing multiple inserts at once.

Comment: Execute it SP outside of INSERT/SELECT,store output in an output parameter variable and use in the WHEN

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I need to grab the dynamic id from the select while doing the insert. CustId would be dynamic and passed into the sproc. I have updated the question to be more accurate.

Comment: You can't do that. What does the stored proc do? Can it be written as a scalar UDF? Or preferably just be inlined entirely?

Comment: Use function instead of procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you convert your 'mySProc' procedure into a Scalar User Defined Function if you want to run it like this. Stored Procedures are not able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then what you need is code to run when the WHEN statement is true.
Just use CASE > WHEN > THEN as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

If you set auto increment for **id** column, not need to mention in the query. If you need, you can add it.

```
Insert into orders(custId, custIntake) 
Select custId, (CASE WHEN custId = '1' THEN 'InsideStore' ELSE 'OutsideStore' END)  from ordersimport;
```

Hope, it will help you.